# Python module paths different after installing through pip

Tags: python, path, pip, setuptools

Suppose I am working on a python project named mymodule, and that I have the following directory structure:

```
mymodule/
   README
   setup.py
   mymodule/
      __init__.py
      foo.py
      bar.py
```

During development I normally work out of the inner `mymodule` folder with all of the source files in it. Because of this, if I was working on `foo` and wanted to import something from `bar`, I would do something like this:

```
from bar import myfunction
```

Everything works fine during development. The problem arises when I want to deploy my module. If I install the module into another project I'm working on, my code no longer works because the modules need to instead be imported like this:

```
from mymodule.bar import myfunction
```

I could change all of my imports in `mymodule` to use this format, however that would mean the module would no longer work in development. When I fix the code for deployment, I break it for development, and vice versa.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your path the same everywhere? Sounds like you might have '.' as a part of your path in one place but not the other.

Comment: Yes, path is the same. Of course I could do some python path trickery in my module code, so that it would work, but I feel like that's a hack. I'm sure there's a better way, I just don't know what the convention is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the cleanest way, but I ended up just prefixing all my imports with `mymodule.`. If I need to develop locally, I just run `pip install .` in the root directory. If I make any changes, I need to uninstall and reinstall, but at least it works. I'm sure there's some PATH trick that would prevent me from having to do this.

Hope this helps